# How can I change the standard "save as" filetype of Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

In which weird file format, unreadable to other applications, does [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) save its files and how I can change it?

I searched through all the settings/options, but didn't find anything.

How can I change the standard "save as" filetype of Notepad++?

Comment: I don't understand the statement "weird file format". When you create a new file the standard save is to save it as a normal text file. If you open an existing file and choose Save As the default format is the same as the file extension you opened. Is NP++ behaving differently from that?

Comment: What other applications are not able to open files saved by Notepad++?

Comment: @grunwald.philipp: can you elaborate on what you mean by "weird file format"? E.g. is it about ASCII/UTF-8/Unicode?

Comment: @Beaner: It seems the default format isn't/wasn't *.txt on my side.

@heavyd+Mortensen: Dunno, I'm no expert in file format analysis. As I have found the correct answer, I'm wondering if that helps you get my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to change the default file format for new documents that Notepad++ uses when you run the program from the icon. If that's correct. You can change the File format of a new document like this.

1. Navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++`
2. Then open the file `config.model.xml` (if you use Notepad++ to edit you won't be able to save as the file is in use.)
3. Look for this line around line #28
   `<GUIConfig name="NewDocDefaultSettings" format="0" encoding="0" lang="1" />`
4. Then you have to change the value for "lang=0" by default it opens everything in txt format. If you look at step 3 I have "1" because I use it for PHP.  You'll have to check the source code if you want to change it to anything else. As the developers did not list all the languages in this configuration file you could use.

Post back if you need further explanation.

Comment: For reference: format="0" is Windows/DOS line ending sequence (CR LF). encoding="0" is for ANSI (others are UCS2Big/UCS2small/UTF8/UTF8-BOM).

Comment: Thanks Kelbizzle, indeed this helped! 

It seems I already achieved this, as I do have lang="0" activated in the file. Must've happened as I looked through the settings and changed some, I just don't know anymore which setting in the GUI this relates to.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: Thanks for the comment, improved my understanding.

Comment: which file format did you want to default it to?

Answer (score 7):

The list for file associations, picked up from the source code.
Just change the set `lang="langID"`

```
    <associationMap>
    <!-- langID:
        L_TEXT: 0     L_PHP: 1        L_C: 2        L_CPP: 3       L_CS: 4         L_OBJC: 5
        L_JAVA: 6     L_RC: 7         L_HTML: 8     L_XML: 9       L_MAKEFILE: 10  L_PASCAL: 11
        L_BATCH:12    L_INI: 13       L_ASCII: 14   L_USER: 15     L_ASP: 16       L_SQL: 17
        L_VB: 18      L_JS: 19        L_CSS: 20     L_PERL: 21     L_PYTHON: 22    L_LUA: 23
        L_TEX: 24     L_FORTRAN: 25   L_BASH: 26    L_FLASH: 27    L_NSIS: 28      L_TCL: 29
        L_LISP: 30    L_SCHEME: 31    L_ASM: 32     L_DIFF: 33     L_PROPS: 34     L_PS: 35
        L_RUBY: 36    L_SMALLTALK:37  L_VHDL: 38    L_KIX: 39      L_AU3: 40       L_CAML: 41
        L_ADA: 42     L_VERILOG: 43   L_MATLAB: 44  L_HASKELL: 45  L_INNO: 46      L_SEARCHRESULT: 47
        L_CMAKE: 48   L_YAML: 49      L_COBOL 50    L_GUI4CLI: 51  L_D: 52         L_POWERSHELL: 53
        L_R: 54       L_JSP: 55
    -->
        <association langID="1" id="php_function"/>
        <association langID="2" id="c_function"/>
        <association langID="3" id="c_cpp_function"/>
        <association langID="6" id="java"/>
        <association langID="9" id="xml_node"/>
        <association langID="12" id="batch_label"/>
        <association langID="13" id="ini_section"/>
        <association langID="19" id="js_function"/>
        <association langID="21" id="perl_function"/>
        <association langID="26" id="bash_function"/>
        <association langID="28" id="nsis_syntax"/>
    <!--
        if langID cannot be found above, you can still set the file extensions
        <association ext=".my_passer_ext1" id="my_passer_id"/>
        <association ext=".my_passer_ext2" id="my_passer_id"/>

        for User Defined Languages:
        <association userDefinedLangName="my user defined language" id="my_udl_passer_id"/>
        <association userDefinedLangName="Autocad" id="my_autocad_passer_id"/>
    -->

    </associationMap>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this, saved me another Google search :)

Comment: which one would be for `All Types` ??  in other words, it would just save whatever extension I provide for it.  I don't want it to be `.txt` `.php` etc

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Settings* -> *Preferences* -> *File Association* and from the *Supported extensions:* section, select the file type you always want the file to be saved by default. For example, if you want to set the default file type as HTML, select *web script* and then select ".html" from the right panel. Click "-->" and save. Next time, your document's default type will be "HTML".

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you want every new document that you generate to be (example: xml)

1 Go to Settings > New Document > Default Language. 
2 From the menu Select (example: xml) from the provided list. 
 
3 Click close and you are done.

Now every time you create a new document it will be in (example: xml) format.

Comment: Can you add some screen shot with this procedure?