# How can I make Notepad++ "save as" default to a file extension based on the selected syntax highlighting language?

Tags: notepad++, save-as

Let's say I write a Java class in Notepad++. I choose "java" in the language menu, and when I save the file it will automatically be a .java file. Well atleast it used to. I just reinstalled notepad++ and this doesnt work anymore. Anyone know how to fix it? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you look at your language settings file? (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\langs.xml) There should be an entry with **<Language name="java" ....** - the extension should be ext="java"

Comment: Thanks. It was already correct, so I guess the problem lies somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with it saving dependent on the syntax but I know that you can change the default file type that it saves as. If that would work for you, there is already a thread about that here and how to change it.

[How can I change the standard "save as" filetype of Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/113957/how-can-i-change-the-standard-save-as-filetype-of-notepad)